# Can we reconsider questions asking for tools

Tags: discussion, scope, recommendation-questions

We know questions asking for programming tools/libraries are considered off-topic. The reason given in the message is that most of the answers will be opinion-based.

I must admit that I saw answers on those questions (before they got closed) and most of them are opinion-based but that's because the question isn't specific,in most times, the OPs don't mention the goal nor the features they want, they just say for example "I want a math library".

But I think we should make questions asking for tools on-topic, opinion-based answers will get downvoted and non-specific questions too. Someone might say "you can't control it and you won't succeed" but take Software Recommendations for example, you can't bypass the fact that it works and it succeeded and yet from the title you might think all the answers are opinion-based but by putting some rules on a good question asking for a software and rules on good answer, they managed it, so why can't we?

PS: right now the closed questions for this reason should remain closed until they get edited.

Comment: Software Recommendations was created *specifically* so some of the off-topic questions on SO can find a home. Why revert that if it so obviously works?

Comment: Also if looking for a resource for the "best" tool or product, check out http://slant.co

Comment: *"take Software Recommendations for example, you can't bypass the fact that it works and it succeeded"* - Exactly. It succeeded on Software Recommendations, which means SR is a fine place for you to ask.

Answer (score 16):

**No.**

> ... take Software Recommendations for example... they managed it, so why can't we?

That argument makes no sense. On that basis, why isn't there just one giant EverythingSE where *any* question is on topic?

SoftwareRecs exists for a reason: to be a place where that type of question is acceptable, within strictly-defined limits. The success or otherwise of that site has no bearing on whether they should be on-topic on SO.

Comment: so basically your answer means "we can ask for a programming tool/library on SR" ?

Comment: @niceman within strictly-defined limits, yes. But certainly not on SO.

Comment: I think I have a feature-request

Comment: @niceman err... OK.

Comment: @niceman Software Recommendations SE works [kinda] well because they have a community specifically dedicated to *only* that type of question. Those questions take a *lot* of moderation effort in order to not become heaping piles of crap. Stack Overflow already has a massive scope and lots of quality guidelines that our members struggle to keep up with as it is. We simply do not have the resources to even consider supporting recommendation questions and all the problems they carry with them here.

Comment: Does it bother anyone that when people ask "how to do something", often get tools as the answers. "Oh yea, that's easy to do, but here's a tool that does it for you" is often the accepted answer.  I find most questions rejected under this premise are because 'there is no tool'.

Comment: @Funkodebat *"here is the tool that does it"* isn't a good answer, but then *"how do I do..."* isn't a good question...

Comment: Shims, workarounds, polyfixes, gists, etc, often times are just plugs of outside software.  Would a good question be: "why do placeholders become the value in IE10-11?"  A good answer would be a fix in a .js file.  That may be an extremely small software tool, but it is a software tool, none the less.  I see no difference in size and scope.

Comment: @Funkodebat ...what? It's not clear what you mean - when you said *"here's a tool that does it for you"* I assumed you meant like a link to an some offsite package, which is the topic of this question. And *"why do placeholders become the value in IE10-11?"* is **not** a question like *"how do I do..."*. An example implementation is often helpful in an answer. That being said, this probably isn't the correct place for discussion - if you have an additional question, please create one.